# Gitlab runner can not clone the repo

Tags: git, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I have a local Gitlab server installed via omnibus, let's call it gitlab.own.com , and I also have a gitlab-runner docker image where I want it to run the ci, they are both on the same machine. I have managed to register the runner but every time the ci runs I get this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601) on runner11 mQZzHdu8 
Using Docker executor with image php:7.0-cli-jessie ...
Pulling docker image php:7.0-cli-jessie ...
Using docker image xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for php:7.0-cli-jessie ...
Running on xxxxxxxxxxxxxx via xxxx... 
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/path/to/.git/ 
Fetching changes...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.own.com:1234/path/to.git/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the network/domain setup. When you run `git clone http://gitlab.own.com:1234/path/to.git/` locally on that machine or inside a docker container, are you able to clone the repository?

Comment: @sauerburger I tried to clone inside the container and I get the same error. I wanted to mention that gitlab is behind basic auth and I usually clone through ssh.

Comment: You are using a public URL which doesn't seem to be public. The domain of your gitlab instance (here gitlab.own.com), does it resolve to the address of your computer? Is there a router in between? Do you have a specific entry in `/etc/hosts`? Can you access gitlab.own.com from another computer?

Comment: @sauerburger yes I add the IP of the box inside the `/etc/hosts` , it is accessible to other computers. Although after restarting the container now I get a connection refused on port 80. Also, gitlab is behind a lighttd proxy.